# TypeError: a float is required - Python

Tags: python, floating-point, typeerror, required

I am currently creating a trigonometric calculator via Python 3.x. In one of my functions, I created a value for an unknown angle of a right triangle 
'angle_b' which I defined by assigning it the function 'ANGLE_B'. Here's the code tree for reference:

```
def create():
    global side_a
    side_a = format(random.uniform(1,100),'.0f')
    global side_b
    side_b = format(random.uniform(1,100),'.0f')
    global angle_a
    angle_a = format(random.uniform(1,180),',.3f')
    global angle_b
    angle_b = ANGLE_B()

def ANGLE_B():
    ang = format(math.asin(side_b*(math.sin(angle_a)/side_a)),'.3f')
    return ang
```

I have tried numerous combinations of converting `ang` in the `ANGLE_B()` block into a floating point number such as `ang = float(ang)` yet i've had no luck. Can anyone help? I keep getting `TypeError: a float is required` when I run it in CMD.

Comment: I don't see the variables `side_b`, `angle_a` and `side_a` declared in your `ANGLE_B()` .. even as `global` ?

Comment: In the `create()` function, `side_a`,`side_b`,`angle_a` and `angle_b` are all declared as global and defined. It's only the `angle_b` variable which is getting defined by the `ANGLE_B()` function, so your vision is very questionable in this case.

Comment: My bad...true...my vision is questionable...:D

Comment: I am wondering why you are creating your variables as strings - rather than creating them as floats, and then only converting to string when you need the output.

Comment: That's a good question. The reason I was converting down was because I wanted the value of the variables to be a constant number rounded to the nearest thousanth. The output is not what I want as much as the actual variable to be like stored so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing string variables to math.sin and math.asin, which is causing the type error. You can fix by converting to float:

```
ang = format(math.asin(float(side_b)* (math.sin(float(angle_a))/float(side_a))),'.3f')
```

You could also just store all these variables as floats to begin with.

Comment: Hi @samgak, I tried this too because I need to use ctypes, and I have the same error, my code:
    `x=0`
    `x=float(x)`
    `fp = c_float(x)`
    `fp = c_float(fp)` Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexanderDeLeonVI the problem is the last statement `fp = c_float(fp)`. You need to pass a float to c_float(), but fp is already c_float because of `fp = c_float(x)`. Just remove the last statement, it's unnecessary.